# Assigning Dynamic variables TO other variable in loop in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am using R to perform big data analysis (C5.0 or Neural Network) with my data which is imported from Matlab using R.matlab package. Since the result for each participant is a 136x137 correlation matrix, I created variables corresponding to each of them (So the variable sub001 will contain the matrix of subject 1 and the variable sub002 will contain that of subject 2 and so on). After that I want to transform the matrix into vectors.

Assuming I have the code for the matrix to vector transformation so that:

`vector <- mat2vec(matrix)`

So I wrote the following codes:

```
#transforming the correlation matrix to 1D vectors
for (i in 1:n){
  if (i < 10){
    vecName <- paste("sub00",i,"_vec",sep = "")
    matName <- paste("sub00",i,"$Z",sep = "")#Z is the subset corresponding to the correlation matrix in the entire data set from Matlab
  }
  if (i >= 10 && i < 100){
    vecName <- paste("sub0",i,"_vec",sep = "")
    matName <- paste("sub0",i,"$Z",sep = "")#Z is the subset corresponding to the correlation matrix in the entire data set from Matlab
  }
  if (i >= 100 && i < 1000){
    vecName <- paste("sub",i,"_vec",sep = "")
    matName <- paste("sub",i,"$Z",sep = "")#Z is the subset corresponding to the correlation matrix in the entire data set from Matlab
  }
  assign(vecName,mat2vec(matName))
}
```

However, it doesn't work as it reported that R sees matName in mat2vec function as the string "sub001$Z" instead of the correlation matrix in the array sub001.  Can any one provide me some suggestion on how I should amend my coding to make it works?

Comment: Why is turning them all into local variables better than just keeping them in the matrix?

Comment: You mean why turning them into vectors? It is because my next step is to combine all the vectors into a giant matrix and then use it for big data analysis (e.g. C5.0, or neural network)

Comment: No, my question is about this: "Since the result for each participant is a 136x137 correlation matrix, I created variables corresponding to each of them". It seems like you have a matrix, then extract individual (rows|columns) into separate local variables, based on that (I can't read R). Is that correct? If not, you'll want to update the description. If so, why would you want to do that? It seems like unnecessary difficulties.

Comment: I see. in fact I am importing data from Matlab to R using R.matlab package, so in each .mat file I have multiple data (correlation matrix, behavioral results etc.) from one participant.  All I need from the data is the correlation matrix, so in the code above I wrote `matName <- paste("sub00",i,"$Z",sep = "")` in which $Z indicates I just want the correlation matrix out of all the data I got from the .mat file.  Hope the explanation helps.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Sort of. Thanks! (also, you'll get better answers if you specify what you mean by "it doesn't seem to work" -- how is it failing? [Edit] that into the question)

Comment: Thank you! I have edited accordingly.